# where can I find class file when jsp page converted into Servlet class?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I can't find my converted servlet class file after compiling jsp file,
I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.4 and Tomcat 9.
I have already searched file in the tomcat's work folder and i am in a window pc.

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\work\Catalina\localhost
```

Comment: i mean where the jsp class file is located in the storage in my pc, i am using jetBrain, tomcat 9, window 10

Comment: Got your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Find you Tomcat directory. And check this directory. Hope you will get what you finding.

```
"tomcat"/work/Catalina/localhost/"webapp name"
```

Give a shout if it works.